# Can i use Coinbase API with dynamic web application without using Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, bitcoin, coinbase-api

I'm new in Coinbase, but little confused. I get stuck every time with Coinbase API. Have a look at this API .. https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-java

I want to make a project with this API using JSP. Where customer could play a role with Bitcoin. But If you see this API, it generally says to use `Maven`. But i don't know Maven. I've good handling at jsp and servlet. Simply i just know to create a project as "dynamic web project" into Eclipse.

So, Is it possible to use Coinbase API with dynamic web project without using Maven anymore. Please help.

***Help, would be appreciated!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can just download jar from maven repository http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.coinbase.api/coinbase-java/1.5.0 (and all its dependencies...). I highly recommend for you to learn what is maven (or gradle) and just use it to control your libraries. The best solution for now is to just install maven and git and follow the steps in **Manual** section on this page. It will produce for you ready to use jar lib which you can add to your project. The $YOUR_JAR_DIRECTORY change with folder where you want to build this lib.